# how to create a c++\cli wrapper for unmanaged c dll

Tags: c#, c++, c, c++-cli

I'm probably confusing myself but haven't done this before and a bit of direction would be very helpful.
I am trying to call some `C` code from a `C#` application.  I have tried using `PInvoke` but finding it is a bit tricky.  I thought I would try doing a `C++\CLI` wrapper.

There are some complicated structs which have double arrays of variable length which was hard to handle with `PInvoke`.
I've read a bit on how this is done but I can't figure it out.  Most of what I've found relates to wrapping `C++` instead of `C`.  The `C` code is already exporting its functions which works already from a Java application and its `JNA` service.  I have the `C` code, headers, library and dll but would rather not make changes to anything existing so as not upset other consuming applications.  The `C#` application calling it will be 64 bit, most examples are creating win32 libraries, does this matter?

UPDATE: adding code below:
NOTE: this is just one function of several and probably the simplest one but they are all fairly similar.

```
C HEADER:
typedef struct myStruct_t
{
    double prefix[8];
    int length;
    double array[1];
}
myStruct;

C:
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) myStruct *doSomething(const myStruct *input, double a)
{
    myStruct *output;
    //doSomething
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Win32 is the generic name for the Windows API in both 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows. If the C# app is 64 bit, then the DLL you are consuming must be 64 bit. Is it?

Comment: the c dll is 64 bit, the win32 bit of the c++\cli wrapper dll made me think it was 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

There's really very little difference between wrapping C and C++. You need to make a C++/CLI class library. Then you write functions in a managed C++ ref class that wrap the native code.

For instance, suppose the DLL exports this function:

```
int sqr(int x)
```

Then in your class library you would include the header file:

```
#include <mynativelibrary.h>
```

You also need to supply the import library to the linker.

Then you can expose the function. The simplest way is to wrap the functions as static methods of the ref class. For instance:

```
public ref class Class1
{
public:
    static int sqr(int x)
    {
        return ::sqr(x);
    }
};
```

You can then consume this assembly in your C# code as you would any other assembly.

Comment: thanks ill try that.  what if the c function takes in a struct and returns a struct.  how is this handled in the c++ wrapper?

Comment: the function itself isn't defined in a header. only the structs and macros, etc. does that make a difference?

Comment: Obviously you need to adapt and generalise for more complex types. Adapt unmanaged struct to managed ref struct. And so on. I don't believe you that the exported functions are not declared anywhere. I'm a little concerned that you seem to be asking us to teach you C++/CLI here.

Comment: I've had a look through the entire c project and the only place I found the function was in the c file. I did say I had never done this before :)

Comment: That's fine. You then add the .c file to the C++/CLI project and compile it into the C++/CLI assembly. That way you don't need a separate unmanaged DLL. I don't think we can reasonably take you from being a complete novice to a finished product in a Stack Overflow question. I'm sorry that this is not proving helpful to you.

Comment: OK, I've created the clr project, added the headers through the properties include (these headers contain structs, etc.), added an include to the stdafx.h and added the c file to the project.  all looking pretty good so far. two things, trying to compile gives an error saying it cannot compile c file with the \clr option. Also, how to call c code from c++ wrapper

Comment: OK. Two options: Compile as C++, but then you run the risk of the code not working because of subtle differences between C and C++. Or do back to putting the C code into a library. I must say though that the function in the question is a problem. Who allocates that struct? And who deallocates it?

Comment: The struct is variable sized. Using the struct hack. You need a very solid grasp of low level C memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

I have created some projects in VisualStudio 2012 which wraps an old MFC dll with managed code. I did it like this:

1. Create a class library in as CLR.
2. Link the old project to this new project
3. Create wrappers in new project for functions and structures and call the old code.
4. Use the new object in C# code.

Please don't forget to create Unittesting for the managed C++ code. (I always forget...:) )

Good luck.

Comment: can you please! elaborate this in further detail, I'm new in Visual C++ and also facing the same problem

Comment: @Ka7lm1011 Please look at this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/managed-cpp-wrapper-for-unmanaged-code/

Answer (score 1):

If Java can call your C code via jna, then there should be not problem with C# via PInvoke. While C++ interop(using C++/Cli) is one type of PInvoke(Implicit PInvoke), using DllImport is explicit PInvoke.

Implicit PInvoke is useful when you do not need to specify how function parameters will be marshaled, or any of the other details that can be specified when explicitly calling DllImportAttribute, but you need crate an additional C++/CLI Dll.

In both way, you have to deal with marshal native data types to the manage ones, this is unavoidable and painful.

in C#, the struct can be declared as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct myStruct {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        double prefix[] intersects;

        public int length;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
        public double[] array;
    }
```

But for the function, DLLImport can't handle this case because C# can't cannot delete the memory for the unmanaged pointer returned by the function, you can create another  wrap function in C to make it use a out parameter to return the result, in this case, the C# code is:

```
[DllImport("...")]
    public static extern void doSomething([In, Out] myStruct[] results,  myStruct[] input,  int len);
```

Or you can use C++/CLI interop, as it can handle both native and manage types, so the calling sequence is:

1. C# code calls  this C++/CLI function with managed data types:

   ManagedmyStruct[] doSomething( ManagedmyStruct[] input, double a)
2. In C++/CLI function domSomething, it calls the native function, the steps are:

   ManagedmyStruct[] doSomething( ManagedmyStruct[] input, double a)
   {

   ```
     //convert the ManagedmyStruct[] input to native type myStruct* input
     myStruct ret* =  doSomething(input, a);
     //convert ret to managed type ManagedmyStruct[] rets
     return rets;
   ```

   }

Comment: have added code above, mainly wondering how to deal with the struct containing variable length arrays, the one that is size 1 will be variable of size length

Comment: Array of length 1 as final member of struct containing int var with name length is pretty clear indication of C struct hack. So no amount of pinvoke struct marshalling gets this done. You need manual IntPtr marshalling.